# Turn string with numbers to byte array - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I created string that contains numbers by calling string.Join on a byte array:

```
string str = string.Join(", ", arr);
```

(arr is a byte array).

How can I turn the string back to a byte array?

Comment: Use `String.Split` and then `Byte.Parse`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Split` and then `Byte.Parse` to parse the string, eg :

```
var newArray = str.Split(',').Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

`Byte.Parse` ignores whitespace so there's no need to trim

If you create the array like this :

```
var str = String.Join(", ", new byte[]{0xFF,0x05,0x56});
```

The new array produced by splitting:

```
var newArray = Split(',').Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Will contain the values 255, 5 and 86.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your string looks like "1,2,3,4"

`var numArray = str.Split(',').Select(s => Byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();`

Runnable:

https://rextester.com/XOMQ99840